# My API request is slow - where to start investigation on what is causing delays?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, restify

I have app hosted on heroku + heroku postgres instance.
My REST api fetches some data from DATABASE and returns data back to client.
I am using `Sequelize.js` as ORM and `restify.js` as server.
My API function looks like this:

```
app.get('/test', function(req,res,next){
   t1 = new Date()

   db.getSomeData.done(function(err,result){

      t2 = new Date()

      console.log((t2.getTime()-t1.getTime())+'ms')

      res.json({}) // it is not mistake, I return empty json to make sure that amount of data transfered back to client is not causing dely
      next()
   })

})
```

For tests I always fetch exactly same data from DB. `console.log` says that DB query takes `400-500ms`. However when I am testing ajax requests (in chrome) and I can see that average request time is `500-800ms`, but from time to time (it happens around 2-3 times per 10 tries) response is received after `3-5 seconds`. This is strange because db query time is still normal (400ms for example) and I am not sending any data back to client. API is used only by me so there is no load on heroku server. I though that it might be caused by my internet connection so I made second test with following handler:

```
app.get('/test', function(req,res,next){
   res.json({}) // it is not mistake, I return empty json to make sure that amount of data transfered back to client is not causing dely
   next()
})
```

And for 100 times ther eis no delay - all requeststs are completed in `73-89` ms.

Do you know what might be a problem? It seems that request sometimes takes more time just because db query was done, no matter how much data is sent back. (despite that db query itself does not take time longer than normal)...

---

That is super-strange because I tried something like this:

```
app.get('/test', function(req,res,next){
   setTimeout(function(){    
      res.json({}) // it is not mistake, I return empty json to make sure that amount of data transfered back to client is not causing dely
      next()
   },500)
})
```

And problem still occurs: 3-4 time per 10 tries response is received after `1.5 - 3.5` seconds where average is `800-900ms`.

---

Also `Response-Time` header set by restify is correct despite the delay. For example:

```
Chrome says: 3.5s
Response-Time: 600s
```

It means that lag is caused by Heroku?

Comment: Let me know if you figure this out. I am having the same issue with Rails!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712817/why-are-my-render-json-data-requests-suddenly-slow-on-heroku

Comment: Hmm my problem seems to be different I think. Have you checked https://status.heroku.com/ - there was some increased HTTP latency issue recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. It was a Heroku platform issue.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649

```
Investigating
Our automated systems have detected potential platform errors. 
We are investigating.

Posted Jul 12, 2014 23:38 UTC
```