# Why are my render json: data requests suddenly slow on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a vague question, but hoping someone just recognizes it.

Sometime today, all my requests that respond as JSON on Heroku are incredibly slow. Regular HTML requests are fine... it's just my controllers that use `render json: XXX` that seem to take 1 minute to respond. I didn't update my app, or change ANYTHING at all within the system.

Does this symptom ring a bell for anyone? Or can anyone give me advice on how to further diagnose?

I know it's not the database, because I made a simple route that just returned a string as a JSON object, and even that route takes 1 min to respond.

Here's hoping.

EDIT: The only thing I did lately was upgrade to 2 web dynos. But I tested briefly with 2 dynos and everything seemed to be working fine...

EDIT2: To make it weirder... logging reveals the request is very fast!! But it just doesn't display on the browser for a good minute or so. wtf?

`Jul 12 05:26:08 appbeta app/web.2:  Processing by UsersController#show as JSON 
Jul 12 05:26:08 appbeta app/web.2:    Parameters: {"id"=>"test_user"} 
Jul 12 05:26:08 appbeta app/web.2:  Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 0.4ms)`

Like, this request occurs... fast right? But it doesn't show on my screen for a whole minute or so.

Comment: Possibly related to my [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717495/slow-page-load-on-heroku)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. It was a Heroku platform issue.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649

```
Investigating
Our automated systems have detected potential platform errors. 
We are investigating.

Posted Jul 12, 2014 23:38 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

I found information on Twitter that fixed my issue.

this seems to be related to websockets.  Disabling it seems to cure the issues.

```
heroku labs:disable websockets -a myapp -p production
```

this makes it work as it used to, though the logs now look different :)

thanks to @dwaynemac @stephane_tavera on twitter.

**EDIT**:

Heroku shows this as a resolve issue, but answer applies in case it happens again.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649#update-2163